# One way authentication

Tags: one-way-function

I need an advice:

I found a paper describing an authentication exchange using a PSK done in this way:

A    --->    B

"A" and "B" have a common PSK.

"A" extracts a random number and then send 2 values to "B"

Value1:   hash( "TAG" XOR "PSK|RANDOM NUMBER" )
Value2:         "RANDOM NUMBER" XOR "PSK"

So, V1 is a hash on an XOR between a TAG (identifier known by the two endpoints) and the PSK appended to the random number.
V2 is the XOR between the random number and PSK.

To verify this, "B" extracts the random number from V2 (knowing the PSK) and then compute the same
HASH, with the same TAG. If this matches, the authentication is OK.
Now, I'd like to remove the TAG from the picture here (since I actually don't need this value and probably it
was introduced in the original algorithm to identify the destination of the communication).
So at the end, I'll have a hash on PSK|RANDOM NUMBER, leaving out the TAG.

Do you think that doing this is breaking or weakening the robustness of the algo?

The paper I found is https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328429210_Survey_on_Prominent_RFID_Authentication_Protocols_for_Passive_Tags

Page 10 describes the auth protocol.

Thanks for your help, and sorry if I was not clear enough in my explanation.

Comment: I think the use of TAG is possibly done like a userid , something like for an organization there is a common PSK and different users are identifying themselves with a different userid which is the TAG in this case. Even if you do not want to use TAG i would suggest that you keep it , since it also contributes to the Randomness of the Value 1